# ASP.NET data corruption via WebClient.OpenWriteCompleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, silverlight-5.0

Trying to upload a data byte[] to ASP.NET via "WebClient" and OpenWriteCompleted in **Silverlight5**.  If the data size is smaller all the data gets written correctly.  If I upload say a 500kb file I get data corruption.

How do I upload a 500kb file to ASP.NET ??

**NOTE: I'm trying to upload a zip file into a MSSQL varbinary(MAX) column in my database.**

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a zip compression bug on my part.